# How can I validate "number of digits" from joi using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

i want that if the number of digits in the input field in less/more than 14(for example) then joi should return an error.

how can i do this with the type of **number** not for string.

Comment: means digit must me equal 14 character ?

Comment: yes @Saurab Mistry

Answer (score 19):

Validation for 10 digit numeric mobile number are given below

```
joi.string().length(10).pattern(/^[0-9]+$/).required(),
```

You should change the rule as per your requirement. pattern(your regex) is used to accept only digits, length() is used to validate how many character validation accepts and only work with string function.

Comment: There is also `\d` in js regex. Hence you can also write `joi.string().length(10).pattern(/^\d+$/).required(),`

Answer (score 4):

Validation for 10 digit numeric mobile number with custom error message are given below

```
joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{10}$/).messages({'string.pattern.base': `Phone number must have 10 digits.`}).required()
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Hapi/joi doesn't presently have a digit count check for numbers. While Sachin Shah is correct that you must convert the number to a string, you must also pass a regex to the validator to ensure that only numeric values are allowed:

`joi.string().length(14).regex(/^\d+$/)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom validator

```
Joi.object({
phone: Joi
    .string()
    .custom((value, helper) => {
        // you can use any libs for check phone
        if (!checkPhone(value)) {
            return helper.message("phone is incorrect"); 
        } // this is what was added
        return value

    })
}).validate({
   phone: '+79002940163'
});
```

Docs:
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anycustommethod-description

Answer (score 3):

```
For Mobile number:

mobile: Joi.number().integer().min(10 ** 9).max(10 ** 10 - 1).required().messages({
        'number.min': 'Mobile number should be 10 digit.',
        'number.max': 'Mobile number should be 10 digit'
    })

For other digit check:

yourparam: Joi.number().integer().min(1000).max(9999).required().messages({
        'number.min': 'OTP should be 4 digit.',
        'number.max': 'OTP should be 4 digit'
    })
```

Comment: If we are trying to store the Number in our MongoDB in Number Type. Then it works.
Apart from it above solutions are listed for String Type.

Answer (score 0):

> For example  birth_year an integer between 1900 and 2013

```
birth_year: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .min(1900)
        .max(2013)
```

You can use like this for number with joi. For reference [Official Readme](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)

> Like this u can pass your min and max values to validate

Comment: how can we do the same for Aadhaar Number

Comment: do u need to validate aadhar card number is valid r not else just validate the number of digits

Comment: in this case just aadhar number but wants to know for others number too.

Comment: To check the given number is aadhar number or not, u need to use some third party api's. If need to validate digits alone joi is a good choice.

Comment: that Joi validation doesn't work for validating number of digits

Answer (score 0):

Joi converts strings if it can by default, that's all in the [documentation](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#number---inherits-from-any). Globally disable [convert](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyoptionsoptions) or use [strict](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anystrictisstrict) on that specific schema.

Answer (score 0):

`minCount: Joi.number().strict()`

if you are using @hapi/joi

Comment: kindly expatiate on your answer

Answer (score -3):

You can use it's `min` and `max` methods.

```
joi.number().min(14)
joi.number().max(14)
```

If it's fine with string then you can do this also.

```
joi.string().length(14).required()
```

And while you read the data for db operation, you can use `+` with value. It will convert your string into integer. But make sure your db allows this big value as a integer if database is mysql. I suggest you to user string as a data type.

```
let obj = {
    number: +req.body.number
}
```

Comment: will it take the number which contains 14 digit? for example: 12345678901234

Comment: @RaviSingh Yes, and this is not a big deal to try your own. Instead of aking this query, you should try it and I'm sure it will not take much time. :)

Comment: i think i don't want to typecast it to number. or joi don't have any method so that i can really use it instead of writing my own logics